# Proving $\Pi$ is a subgroup of $\Pi_{\alpha,c}G_{\alpha}$ is a subgroup of $\Pi_{\alpha}G_{\alpha}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider a collection of finite groups $\{G_{\alpha}, \cdot_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in A}$ and define the subset of $\Pi_{\alpha}G_{\alpha}$

\begin{equation}
\Pi_{\alpha, c}G_{\alpha} := \{f \in \Pi_{\alpha}G_{\alpha}: f(\alpha)=e_{\alpha} \ \text{for all but finitely many} \ \alpha \},
\end{equation}
here $e_{\alpha} \in G_{\alpha}$ is the identity element in $G_{\alpha}$. Is $\Pi_{\alpha, c}G_{\alpha}$ a subgroup of $\Pi_{\alpha}G_{\alpha}$? If it is, do there exist elements in $\Pi_{\alpha, c}G_{\alpha}$ with infinite order?

I'm not sure on how to start the first question. I think I might need to use the Finite Group Test, but I'll have to prove that $\Pi_{\alpha, c}G_{\alpha}$ is nonempty first, which requires me to prove that it includes the identity element. What would the identity element look like? Also, any idea on the second question would be appreciated.

Comment: The identity element is the function with $f(\alpha) = e_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in A$.

Comment: How would we prove that it exists in $\Pi_{\alpha, c}G_{\alpha}$?

Comment: It is obviously satisfies the required condition that $f(\alpha) = e_\alpha$ for all but finitely many $\alpha$.